# How to Select UTF8(Persian) Characters From MySQL With Using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8, farsi

I Want To Read Persian Characters From MySQL With PHP.Characters Are Well Stored By PHP In MySQL.
But When Reading Them The Characters Are In The Form Of "?".

This Is My Data In MySQL:

[My SQL Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Wjt.png)

This Is My Code For Select Data:

```
$Query = "SELECT ID,Json FROM su";
$MySQLAddress = "___";
$MySQLUsername = "___";
$MySQLPassword = "___";
$MySQLDataBaseName = "___";
$MySQLConnection = mysqli_connect($MySQLAddress,$MySQLUsername,$MySQLPassword,$MySQLDataBaseName);
if ($MySQLConnection -> connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $MySQLConnection -> connect_error;
      exit();
}
$MySQLConnection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$MySQLConnection->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$MySQLConnection->query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'");
$Result = $MySQLConnection->query($Query);
```

But This Is My Result:
[Data Table Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtS3Q.png)

Comment: Remove all these SET lines and add `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');` just like is shown in the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: What encoding do you use to display the characters? It might be that you receive the characters correctly, but display them using incorrect format

Comment: I encoded the characters with utf8. Unfortunately your code does not work!

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored